# why size_t variable, int constant comparison doesn't work properly while off_t variable works fine?

Tags: c, casting, integer, typechecking, size-t

I was trying to compare `size_t`(`long int` type for ubuntu) variable with `int` constant `0` but turned out not working properly. but `off_t` variable works fine.

```
size_t var = -3;

if(var < 0)
    putchar('X');
else
    putchar('Y');

// Y
```

but when I cast `var` into `int`, it works as I expect.

```
size_t var = -3;

if((int)var < 0)
    putchar('X');
else
    putchar('Y');

// X
```

but `off_t`(`long int` as well on my ubuntu) works fine without casting.

```
off_t var2 = -3;

if(var2 < 0)
    putchar('X');
else
    putchar('Y');

// X
```

Could you explain this please? Thanks.

Comment: `size_t` is *not* signed (see [https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t]). Are you talking of `ssize_t`?

Comment: Assuming you are using gcc or clang, I recommend in the future you turn on the `-Wsign-compare` warning so you can detect and fix this type of bug at compile time.

Comment: hoo, Save time and enable all warnings to see the trouble quickly with `size_t var = -3;` and `if(var < 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `size_t` is an unsigned type.  So when you attempt to assign the value -3 to it, the value gets converted into a very large positive value.  This is why the condition in the first case is false.

In the second case, when casting `var` to an `int`, the assigned value (i.e. the very large positive value from before) is outside the range of `int` so it gets converted in an implementation defined manner.  On most implementations, this will result the value being converted to -3, so the condition will be true.

The type `off_t` is a signed type so it is able to store the value -3, so the comparison works as expected.

Comment: "... value gets converted into a very large positive value. This is why the condition in the first case is false."  --> True in OP's code, yet the condition is false for all `size_t`, even 0, not only large values.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is an unsigned integer type, per C 2018 7.19 2. For illustration, in this answer I will treat it as 32 bits, with maximum value 4,294,967,295 (2<sup>32</sup>−1), and I will treat `int` as 32 bits, with minimum value −2,147,483,648 and maximum value +2,147,483,647. Widths of integer types can differ between C implementations.

For `size_t var = -3;`, −3 is converted to the unsigned type. This conversion wraps modulo 4,294,967,296 (2<sup>32</sup>), so 4,294,967,293 is stored in `var`.

In `var < 0`, the `int` `0` is converted to `size_t`. This does not change the value; the result of the conversion is 0, just with type `size_t`. Then the two `size_t` values 4,294,967,293 and 0 are compared. Since 4,294,967,293 is not less than 0, the result of the comparison is false (zero).

In `(int)var < 0`, the `size_t` `var` is converted to `int`. Since 4,294,967,293 is greater than our `int` can represent, the conversion is specified in C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, which says the result is implementation-defined. In common C implementations, it wraps modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, in which case this conversion produces the value we started with −3. Then the `int` values −3 and 0 are compared. Since −3 is less than 0, the result of the comparison is true (one).

`off_t` is a signed integer type. (This is a Unix or other implementation-defined type, not a part of the C standard.) Since it is capable of representing −3, no change in value occurs when it is initialized with −3, and no change of value occurs when it is compared to `0`.